# Wrong number of contacts showing in Google account

Tags: google-contacts

[image: Google Contacts]

What is the reason for the **(1)** in **My Contacts (1)** on the left? I have clicked the link, but it has no effect. I've refreshed the page a dozen times and still get the same count. Is there a default contact in my list? Might there be any sort of pending process in the background?

Comment: You do appear to have a (blank) contact line/entry with a checkbox to the left? Have you tried clicking on this entry?

Comment: yup..you're right.. a blank entry is there. Now only noted!!

Comment: yes . you can , but I think google should avoid such entry as there is no data in that row. Its a type of bug.

Comment: I thought you were implying that it just contained a "note" ("Now only noted")? Maybe there are other non-visible characters (spaces?) in some of the fields?

Comment: no. everything is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do appear to have one (blank) contact line/entry with a checkbox to the left.

[image: Blank contact record]

You say this record is entirely empty, however, it is possible to create an almost empty contact record with a single space in one of the fields.

Whilst it doesn't seem possible to easily *create* an entirely empty contact record, you can edit that contact record, delete the space (or any data it might contain), save the record, and end up with an entirely blank contact record. Note that Gmail auto-saves contact records, so this could happen without you explicitly do so.

Presumably you can delete this "blank" entry to have an entirely empty contacts list?

Answer (score -1):

I mentioned that the record is entirely empty,

I'll try to display what I've done:
1) tried with `NEW CONTACT` and entered `test@gmail.com` in the field `Email` and clicked outside the form.

[image]

Next, clicked the same field, clikd <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> 
[image]

Now click `My Contacts`, We still see **My Contacts(1)**

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same as what I said in my answer... deleting/emptying the fields of a contact record and saving does not delete the contact record itself. You should note that Gmail auto-saves contacts and emails, without you explicitly doing so. In your first screenshot, you can see that Gmail has saved a valid contact record. In the second step, you are editing it.